# Target Membership

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Can someone tell me what is target membership in Xcode whenever I clicked a implementation file? I'm trying to see if I can launch 2 apps within one Xcode project and wondering if this will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

target membership determines whether the file is "used" in the target. Like if you have "Foo.m" which contains a class that prints "Hello World" and it is member of target "bar" and not of target "eddie" it will only be useable in the "bar" target. So if you try using that class in the "eddie" target you will get an error because the class simply does not exist..

See it as having 2 boxes, and you are trying to decide whether you want the box to have a copy of a certain paper or not..

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, I have quick question, how is Xcode execute the program when developers press Cmd + R?? To give you an insight, I'm trying to combine two Mac OS X apps into one, right now I'm trying to dump application #2's implementation files, frameworks, etc. into application #1's xcode project. And after I run the merged program (and I put NSLog for indicating if #2 is really launch with app #1),the counsel did not indicate #2 is launched? I'm just trying to figure out how I can launch those two together... I know this is a lot, thanks.

Comment: @Eddie.Du not sure.. I never tried that personally with xcode 4 but I think if you select a different scheme ( you know, the dropdown next to the run and stop buttons ), the scheme of target whichever you want, and then press run it'll run that one too..